# How to update jqgrid row id after saving by formatter action save button

Tags: jqgrid

jqGrid edited row id needs to be refreshed after save from id returned in response.
I tried code below but undefined message box appears.

How to update row id ?
How to get response text after row is updated by Save action button ?

Andrus

```
grid.jqGrid({
  colModel: [{name:_actions,width:45,
  formatter:"actions",
  formatoptions:
    {keys:true,
     delbutton:false,
     onSuccess:function (rowID, response) {
      alert(response);             
      $("#" + rowID).attr("id", response.responseText);
      },

    onEdit: function (rowID) {
     if (typeof (lastSelectedRow) !== 'undefined' && rowID !== lastSelectedRow)
       cancelEditing($('#grid'));
       lastSelectedRow = rowID;
     }
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to go back to our old discussion, but I just want to remind that the changing of `id` is not good practice.

You can try to solve the problem by placing of `$("#" + rowID).attr("id", response.responseText);` inside of [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). In the case the changing will be done after processing of the old id in inline editing code.

Moreover you could verify the following. In can be important to rename `id` in some other places saved by jqGrid internally. For example, `selrow` and `selarrrow` where the ids of selected rows will be hold.

Comment: Major issue is that action buttons do not have single event where both old rowid and response text are passed like in inline edit aftersavefunc. I solved this by storing reponse to global variable in `onSuccess =function (jqXHR) {
actionresponse = jqXHR;
return true;
}"` and used this in `afterSave =function (rowID) {
aftersavefunc(rowID,actionresponse)}`. Db scheme uses natural primary key ids and is deployed to thousands of sites. Changing this even creating duplicate surrogate ids as you reccommended is too much work since requires rewriting number of production applications.

Comment: @Andrus: OK, I understand that in case of many old version of your software installed the update scenario could be complex. I didn't thought about the problem. Nevertheless what I suggested you are not changing the primary key of the existing tables. I suggested to add an **additional** column in tables where AUTOINCREMENT value could be saved. After that you could place UNIQUE CONSTRAINT or just an INDEX on the column to have quick search by the value from the column and **use the value as id only for jqGrid**. In your other applications you can continue to use old primary key. It should work

Comment: @Andrus: You should be careful with saving `jqXHR` somewhere. You should write the code so that the pointer will be assigned to `null` if it is not used. If you will don't do this you could have memory leeks because the memory for `jqXHR` could not be released.

Comment: Thank you. empty row is added in loadComplete. If this row is saved in inline edit, jqGrid row id needs to be updated from server response. So this issue **occurs also if integer primary key is used**. After I removed jqID() call from your other sample it looks like natural primary keys work OK with jqGrid without changing schema. I added `actionresponse=null` to afterSave handler. Hopefully this prevents leak.